# Error Updating ACCESS from ADODB Command / Recordset

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access, adodb

First off, I truly apologize if someone promptly points me to a post in which this question was answered.  I'm not great at sifting through the boards, but have been searching for about a week.  Many threads are similar to my problem, but none exactly mirror what I'm trying to do or the problem I'm having.  The closest I've found was posted [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?508103-RESOLVED-Data-Type-Mismatch). The solution reached there did not solve my issue.

I am trying to update records in an ACCESS 2007 database from an update Excel worksheet using VBA. I have accomplished getting information from ACCESS into Excel, and from Excel into my recordset.  Now, I need to update ACCESS with the populated recordset.

```
Public Sub Read_Spreadsheet()
    Dim strSql As String, target_fields As String
    Dim fuel_table As String, new_values As String
    Dim roww As Integer, coll As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, mbrs(32) As Integer
    Call Load_Globals

'   Configure ADODB connection, command, recordset objects
    With cn1
        .Provider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & Src_WB_nm & "; " & _
            "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
        .Open
    End With
    Set cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn1
    cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & Src_WS_nm & "$]"
    With rs1
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient   ' used 3 previously
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic     ' used 1 previously
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmd1
    End With
    Debug.Print "Excel Connection established; recordset created."

    Debug.Print "Fields: " & rs1.Fields.count
    Debug.Print rs1.Fields(0).name
    Debug.Print rs1.Fields(1).name

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With cn2
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & Dest_DB
        .Open
    End With
    With rs2
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient   ' used 3 previously
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic     ' used 1 previously
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    End With
    Debug.Print "Access connection established."

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
'  NOTE to S.O. readers,  Two nested loops are commented out below
'  These will eventually loop through an uncertain number of fields
'  (~10) and records (~2000) to make all the SQL updates.  For debugging,
'  I'm just trying to get 1 pass to be successful.
'
'    For n = 1 To rs1.RecordCount
'  strSql = "SELECT ID, FSERIAL FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID = 1"
        strSql = ""
        i = 1
 '       For i = 1 To rs1.Fields.count - 1
            If i <> 1 Then strSql = strSql & ", "
            strSql = strSql & " SET [" & rs1.Fields(i).name & "] = " & Chr(39) & rs1.Fields(i).Value & Chr(39)
 '       Next i
        strSql = "UPDATE " & Dest_Table & strSql & " WHERE [ID] = " & rs1.Fields(0).Value
        strSql = "UPDATE TESTTABLE SET BATCH = 'B' WHERE ID = 11"

        Debug.Print strSql
        Set cmd2 = New ADODB.Command
        With cmd2
            .ActiveConnection = cn2
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = strSql
            .Execute , , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
        End With
   '     CP.Cells(27 + n, 4) = rs1(0)
   '     CP.Cells(27 + n, 5) = rs1(1)
        rs1.MoveNext
        Set cmd2 = Nothing

'    Next n

 '   cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT ID, FSERIAL FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID = 1"
 '   cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE TESTTABLE SET BATCH = B WHERE ID = 1"
 '   Debug.Print cmd2.CommandText
 '   rs2.Open cmd2
 '   CP.Cells(28, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs2

    Call Close_Connections
End Sub
```

Both Access & Excel are 2007, and I'm in Windows 7, 32 Bit OS.  I'm using the following VBA references: MS ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security, MS ActiveX Data Ojects Recordset 6.0 Lib, MS ActiveX Objeects 6.1 Lib, MS Access 12.0 Object Lib, OLE Automation.  (sorry, I cannot post images yet)

Everything works fine up until the cmd2.execute command (That is the line highlighted by the debugger).  If I replace the SQL query with a simple static SELECT and dump it into rs2, it works fine.  It's when I try to update only that I get the problem.

The debug.print strSQL command yields"'UPDATE TESTTABLE SET BATCH = 'B' WHERE ID = 11"

I've also tried "UPDATE TESTTABLE SET [BATCH] = 'B' WHERE [ID] = 11" and other permutations, with no success.

The error is : "Run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)': No value given for one or more required parameters."

Thank you for your help!  I appreciate it very much, and will be sure to rank/flag the solution.

,Mike Shanahan

Comment: Where do you set the variable `Dest_Table` which is used in the statement `strSql = "UPDATE " & Dest_Table & strSql`?  (As far as I can see, you don't use `strSql`, so it probably doesn't really matter.)

Comment: We need the actual SQL that gives the error when executed. [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Thank you for the replies YowE3K and Andre!  Dest_Table is set = "TESTTABLE" in the Load_Globals subroutine, but I am using a statis strSQL = "..." stmt for debugging purposes.

Comment: Andre, did I sufficiently answer your question in the edit above?  (4th from last paragraph)

Comment: Thanks again for your help gentlemen!  My problem is resolved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is ill-formed. I think what you want is:

```
For i = 1 To rs1.Fields.count - 1
    if i<>1 Then strsql = strsql & ", "
    strSql = strSql & "[" & rs1.Fields(i).name & "] = " & rs1.Fields(i).Value
Next i

strsql = "UPDATE " & Dest_Table & " SET " & strSql & " WHERE [ID] = " & rs1.Fields(0).Value
```

Still, this supposes all values are numeric. You'll need to still work it out so that values corresponding to strings are enclosed with single quotes. For example, your test query should be:

```
.CommandText = "UPDATE TESTTABLE SET BATCH = 'B' WHERE ID = 1"
'                                            ^^^
```

As suggested in comments, a simple `Debug.Print strsql` is very helful to debug your queries.

Comment: Thank you for the correction of my query generation; that would have been a problem down the road for sure!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the immediate problem.  I've modified the code per your recommendations, move the test query statement just below the real query statement, and I removed the loop so as to test a single iteration of the routine.  Still not working.  I've edited my post above with the new code and screen shots of my VBA screen.

Comment: Back up the stage coach!!  My problem is now solved.  I neglected to restart my programs the first time, sometimes my DB connection seems to breakdown after a long bout of debugging.  In any case, I am now up and running!
Thank you so much for the assistance and for your time A.S.H.!

Comment: @MikeShanahan Glad to know all is working now :). You're welcome.